# Why will Facebook not load og:image loaded via a php file?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph, share-open-graph

I'm using a php file to load images into my webpage, since they are hosted outside the webroot. Everything works well apart from Facebook not registering the image in an `og:image` metatag when they are loaded in this way.

Ironically, the page in question is https://www.molecularmagic.net/hosting/the.computing.cafe/www/index.php?t=3b3c55

The metatag in question is:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.molecularmagic.net/hosting/the.computing.cafe/www/file.php?f=feature_image.png">
```

The headers sent along with the image are:

```
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: public, max-age=604800
content-length: 243688
content-type: image/png
date: Sun, 06 Jun 2021 22:56:58 GMT
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
last-modified: Sun, 06 Jun 2021 23:05:22 +0100
server: LiteSpeed
vary: User-Agent
```

In this case, Facebook Sharing Debugger gives me this error:

```
Provided og:image URL, https://www.molecularmagic.net/hosting/the.computing.cafe/www/file.php?f=featured_image.png could not be processed as an image because it has an invalid content type
```

For other pages, the `og:image` tag is:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://openmediavault/the.computing.cafe/www/images/feature_image.png?1623012347">
```

The numbers after the filename are the `filemtime` to force FB to reload the image if I change it. The headers sent with this image are:

```
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: public, max-age=604800
content-length: 183886
content-type: image/png
date: Sun, 06 Jun 2021 22:27:30 GMT
expires: Sun, 13 Jun 2021 22:27:30 GMT
last-modified: Sun, 06 Jun 2021 20:46:04 GMT
server: LiteSpeed
vary: User-Agent
```

...and Facebook Sharing Debugger correctly renders the image.

I've tried very hard to make sure that the headers when the image is sent through `file.php` are as close as possible to the headers sent from a 'real' image file.

I know that this is caused by serving the image through `file.php` but I cannot see why Facebook would tell me that the image has an invalid content type when the headers look identical.

Can anyone suggest why this might be the case?

Comment: sanity check.. go to [the image](https://www.molecularmagic.net/hosting/the.computing.cafe/www/file.php?f=feature_image.png)

Comment: Loads OK for me...

Comment: not for me im getting `File not found: feature_image.png`

Comment: Yes - you cannot load the image without loading the page first. Load https://www.molecularmagic.net/hosting/the.computing.cafe/www/index.php?t=3b3c55 first and then the image. I've used session variables loaded in the page to locate the image.

Comment: the image needs to be hot linkable, the bot is most likely seeing the text not the image, the same server/ip won't be scrapping both the site and images etc

Comment: Damn. That makes sense. I think what I want to do is impossible then?

Comment: network quota is cheap nowadays, is no point preventing access to images, you could even deploy a image/file server `http://images.openmediavault.com/the.computing.cafe/filename.jpg` and use an origin pull cdn, which pulls from the source site, then plop cloudflare in front, then you'll probably find 90% of traffic is cached and doesn't even hit your server

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone - I disabled hotlinking to files to prevent any access outside the page. However, I'm using the same script for images. I will add a new image.php file to allow hotlinking to images and this will hopefully solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - thank you. Was completely solved by making the metadata image hotlinkable.